# Padding inside DIV

Tags: html, css

Why does adding some padding affects elements outside the DIV box? Padding isn't supposed to create some space between the border of the DIV and contents **inside** it? How can you create this space without affecting elements outside the DIv box?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can you create this space without affecting elements outside the
>   DIv box?

Use `box-sizing: border-box`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

> border-box 
>   The width and height properties include the padding and
>   border, but not the margin.

The reason that this property must be set is because by default the value for `box-sizing` is `content-box`. Again from MDN:

> **content-box** This is the default style as specified by the CSS standard. The width and height properties are measured including only
>   the content, but not the padding, border or margin.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have specified a content `height` or `width`, then `padding` will be placed *around* that. That moves the border outwards. That moves the margin outwards. That pushes nearby elements away.

You can change it by reducing the `height` and/or `width` to compensate or by using the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property to make `height` and `width` determine the distance between the outside edges of the border instead of the outside edges of the content.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into the `box-sizing` property...

https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

> Today, the current versions of all browsers use the original "width or
>   height + padding + border = actual width or height" box model. With
>   box-sizing: border-box;, we can change the box model to what was once
>   the "quirky" way, where an element's specified width and height aren't
>   affected by padding or borders. This has proven so useful in
>   responsive design that it's found its way into reset styles.

The value you're after is `border-box`:

```
.class {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```